# Problems using ggplot, assing(paste0)) in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, assign

I am trying to use a for loop in a data.frame to create a number of plots using ggplot. The number of plots vary in different situations. The code I am using is the follow:

```
for(i in colnames(AUX_GRAF[2: ncol(AUX_GRAF)])){
  AUX01 <- as.numeric(AUX_GRAF[, i])
  AUX <- ggplot (AUX_GRAF, 
                              aes(x = reorder(SE, as.numeric(SE)),
                                  y = AUX01)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold")) +
  labs(caption = "Fonte", 
       x = "Semana Epidemiológica",
       y = "Número de Casos",
       title = paste0(i, " - Notificados"))+
  theme( panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#C0C0C0"),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F5F5F5"),
         plot.title = element_text(face = "bold",
                                   size = 15,
                                   colour = "#556B2F")) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black",
           fill = "#8FBC8F") + 
  geom_label(aes(label = AUX01),
             alpha = 0.5,
             vjust = 0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)))
  assign(paste0("SE_HIST_NOT_", i), AUX)  
    Sys.sleep(1)
    print(assign(paste0("SE_HIST_NOT_", i), AUX))
    rm(AUX)
}
```

AUX_GRAF is the data.frame I am trying to plot.
I try different ways to do it and every way I get the same result. The geom_label is right, the title is right, but the geon_bar is always the same as the last iteration.

I do not know what is happening.

I put the Sys.sleep and the rint(assign(paste0("SE_HIST_NOT_", i), AUX)) in the end of the loop to see what is happening, but the plots inside the loop are right.But when I try to plot outside of the loop I have the problem above.

AUX_GRAF

```
> dput(head(AUX_GRAF))
structure(list(SE = c("21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26"), ARAPUÃ = c(2, 
3, 2, 1, 1, 0), ARIRANHA_DO_IVAÍ = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), CÂNDIDO_DE_ABREU = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), CRUZMALTINA = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), GODOY_MOREIRA = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0), IVAIPORÃ = c(39, 32, 18, 16, 14, 10), JARDIM_ALEGRE = c(11, 
19, 7, 2, 0, 0), LIDIANÓPOLIS = c(22, 18, 9, 9, 4, 11), LUNARDELLI = c(12, 
2, 3, 3, 7, 2), MANOEL_RIBAS = c(5, 5, 1, 0, 3, 1), MATO_RICO = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), NOVA_TEBAS = c(15, 19, 11, 7, 3, 5), RIO_BRANCO_DO_IVAÍ = c(10, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0), ROSÁRIO_DO_IVAÍ = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SANTA_MARIA_DO_OESTE = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SÃO_JOÃO_DO_IVAÍ = c(3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The variable inside the loop is right: print(assign(paste0("SE_HIST_NOT_", i), AUX)), the problem is when I try to plot (assign(paste0("SE_HIST_NOT_", i), AUX))) outside the loop.

Comment: Is `SE` the first column? The x axis is always ordered, why are you reordering `SE`?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(AUX_GRAF)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(AUX_GRAF, 20))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

So I will first reformat the data, split by groups of `"Fonte"` (municipalities), then `lapply` an anonymous plotting function to each group.

I have also created a custom theme, it later simplifies the plotting code.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

theme_so_q76956453 <- function(){ 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10) %+replace%    #
    theme(
      axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#C0C0C0"),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F5F5F5"),
      plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15, colour = "#556B2F")
    )
}

AUX_GG_LIST <- AUX_GRAF %>%
  pivot_longer(-SE, names_to = "Fonte") %>% 
  mutate(
    SE = as.integer(SE),
    Fonte = gsub("_", " ", Fonte)
  ) %>%
  group_split(Fonte) %>% 
  lapply(\(dados) {
    titulo <- dados$Fonte %>% unique() %>% paste0(" - Notificados")
    ggplot(dados, aes(x = SE, y = value)) + 
      geom_col(color = "black", fill = "#8FBC8F") + 
      geom_label(aes(label = value), alpha = 0.5, vjust = 0.1) +
      labs(
        caption = "Fonte", 
        x = "Semana Epidemiológica",
        y = "Número de Casos",
        title = titulo
      ) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05))) +
      theme_so_q76956453()
  })

# needed because that's the result AUX_GG_LIST order
# (given by dplyr::group_split)
old_loc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
AUX_GG_LIST <- setNames(AUX_GG_LIST, names(AUX_GRAF)[-1] |> sort())
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", old_loc)

# the plots are all different, for instance the 1st and the 3rd
AUX_GG_LIST[[1]]
```

[image]

```r
# same as next plot, commented out
# AUX_GG_LIST[[3]]
AUX_GG_LIST$CRUZMALTINA
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, Rui Barradas. The problem remains. In my current loop, 16 plots are made. The 16 plots have 10 bars each. What differs betwen then is the title, the geom_label and the bars (geom_bar). the 16 plots are perfect, the geom label is right, the title is right, but the bars are equal in all 16 graphs. Thats is weird, they are all equal to the last iteration. I tryied before using list, but i had the same result. I tried to remove the AUX to "force" the R to create a new AUX. the weird thing is that inside the loop every thing is fine. the problem is when I call the graff outside the loop.

Comment: I tried with your code, but i had the same result.

Comment: The geom_label is right, but he explicit the label of the bars of the last iteration.

Comment: Using the Rui Brabosa's code, I had the same problem. I had a list with 16 graffs, with 16 titles (as it should be), but the bars and the geom_label is all the same as the last iteration.

Comment: @Gustavo I have changed the code to `force` evaluation of `AUX`, see if this solves the problem.

Comment: Did not work. I put the sample of the AUX_GRAF in the question. The strange thing is that inside the loop, when i ask to print the assign(paste0(...  it works. The graphs are perfect. The problem is outside the loop.

Comment: @Gustavo Thanks for the data, it made things much easier. See if the problem is now solved, Boa sorte.

Comment: Hi, Rui Barradas. Thank you!!! Worked perfectly!!